# Using a undefined structure is not throwing an error

Tags: c, unions

I have a code snippet like -

```
typedef struct {
    int data;
    struct abc *nxt;              // Have not defined the structure of name "abc"
} mynode_t;
```

Here I have not defined a structure of name "abc". Still this code doesn't throw an error and compiles fine.
Can anyone help understand how this piece of code is working fine?

Please note: Instead "abc", even if I give some other name like "xyz", it works

Comment: It's not a problem, because it is just a pointer, so the compiler knows how much space to reserve for it. If you tried to dereference it without having defined the datatype `struct abc`, you will get an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C language allows pointers to structures which haven't been defined.

Without this feature, it wouldn't be possible to create constructs like the following:

```c
struct LinkedListNode {
   struct LinkedListNode *nxt;
   void *data;
};
```

When the compiler encounters `struct LinkedListNode *nxt;` in the above, `struct LinkedListNode` hasn't been defined yet since we're in the process of defining it.

Note that code that dereferences `nxt` or otherwise needs info about the structure will require the structure to be defined.

---

Incomplete structure pointers are also useful for creating opaque types. For example, a library might present the following interface:

```c
typedef struct LibData *LibHandle;

LibHandle Lib_new( void );
void Lib_delete( LibHandle );
int Lib_do_something( LibHandle, int );
```

To the user of this library, `LibHandle` is opaque, meaning it's only useful as a value to pass to the library functions. This allows the library to change the format of `LibData` over time without causing backwards-compatibility issues.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that it works only with a pointer (because all pointers have the same size). It would not work if `nxt` in the OP's code was not a pointer.

Comment: @wohlstad, Clarified.

Comment: @wohlstad, Re "*because all pointers have the same size*", No, they don't (necessarily). But for pointers to structures, yes.

Comment: @ikegami If you feel to be nitpicking here, you should at least elaborate what you dispute here. I think it's clear, that it was meant, that all data pointers on the same platform have the same size, which is true in my eyes

Comment: @ikegami I am aware of some anomaly in pointers size in C++ (for pointers to members). I thought in C they should all have the same size - at least for a given platform (otherwise how can the compiler know the size of the struct containing the undefined pointer?).

Comment: @Ctx, Re "*that all data pointers on the same platform have the same size,*", Again, this is wrong. Pointers on the same platform are not guaranteed to all be the same size. Like I said above. C only guarantees that `void *` is large enough to represent any pointer except a function pointer, and that struct pointers are the same size.

Comment: @wohlstad, Re "*I thought in C they should all have the same size*", See previous comment. /// Re "*otherwise how can the compiler know the size of the struct containing the undefined pointer?*", struct pointers are guaranteed to be the same size.

Comment: @ikegami missed that, understood. +1.

Comment: @ikegami BTW - I haven't encountered an actual platform where data pointers have different size. Have you (just out of curiosity) ?

Comment: @wohlstad it does not matter. C standard does not give any provisions for this claim. The implementation is free to do whatever is needed. But some platforms have short and long pointers

Comment: @gulpr I understood it is not mandatory that all pointers have the same size. As I said I asked about such platforms out of curiosity because I haven't encountered such ones.

Comment: @wohlstad, DOS, for one.

Comment: @ikegami interesing. I actually used DOS many years ago. My memory is probably failing me ;-)

Comment: @wohlstad, I said DOS, but I meant 16-bit x86 processors. Their addresses consisted of 16-bit segment + a 16-bit offset to effectively form a 20-bit address (`seg << 4 | off`). (This explains the 1 MiB memory limit.) So a pointer would take 32 bits. But what if the program had a constant value in a segment register (e.g. DS)? Then, you would have up to 64 KiB of memory that would be addressable using only a 16-bit offset. These were called near pointers. `.com` programs (as opposed to `.exe` programs) were basically 64 KiB memory images, so they tended to work exclusively with near pointers.

Comment: @ikegami I now vaguely recall the issue of near and far pointers. But in that case all struct pointers must be either one or the other, right ? Because otherwise it would violate the rule that all struct pointers have the same size.

Comment: IIRC, compilers introduced `near` and `far` keywords to tell the compiler which kind of pointer to use. If so, you could still have two sizes for struct pointers without causing problems.

Comment: @ikegami it's all clear now.

Answer (score 4):

You are not using this structure, you are only declaring the reference (pointer) to it. It is legal, but if you try to dereference it or take `sizeof` of it will produce the error as this structure declaration **is incomplete**.

```
typedef struct {
    int data;
    struct abc *nxt;   //forward declaration of struct abc
} mynode_t;

void foo(void)
{
    mynode_t mn;
    mn.nxt = NULL;  //OK
}

void bar(mynode_t *mn)
{
    mn -> nxt -> something = 5; //wrong
}

void zoo(mynode_t *mn)   
{
    mn -> nxt = malloc(sizeof(*mn -> nxt));  //wrong
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/PzebnbP5h

If you want `nxt` to reference the same struct type you need to use **tag**

```
typedef struct abc{
    int data;
    struct abc *nxt;             
} mynode_t;
```